# Python to see if a file falls into a date range

Tags: python, time, date, range

I have a script that I want to have an if statement check if a file falls between several specified date periods as it searches directories. I have been able to get the time in %Y-%m-%d format for the file, but I can't seem to be able to specify a date range for python to go through. Any ideas/help?

Here's what I have so far

```
for name in files:
    f = os.path.join(root, name)
    dt = os.path.getmtime(f)
    nwdt = time.gmtime(dt)
    ndt = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', nwdt)
```

Comment: This is off-topic, and should be on Stack Overflow instead of Super User

Answer (score 1):

```
if datetime.datetime(...) < datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dt) < datetime.datetime(...):
   ...
```